# Library application. Stuck on edit book method

Tags: java

having trouble with this method. Can anyone spot an obvious mistake? When I run the program and it asks me to enter an ID to edit, I enter a correct one but it says "this ID already exsists" .. I only want it to say that after I edit the ID of the book, if that makes sense. Any help much appreciated.

```
public void editBook(ArrayList<Book> books) {

    boolean exsistingID = false;
    int editID, ID;
    String newTitle, newAuthor, newPublisher;
    int newReleaseYear;
    //int newNumLoans;
    //boolean newOnLoan;

    do {
        System.out.println("Enter the ID of the book you wish to edit: ");
        editID = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        if (editID == 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - Book ID can not be 0. Please try again");
        }
    } while (editID == 0);

    for (int a = 0; a < books.size(); a++) {
        Book z = books.get(a);
        if (editID == (z.getBookID())) {
            exsistingID = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (exsistingID == true) {
        System.out.println("This ID already exists. Please try again");
        do {
            System.out.println("Enter a new ID: ");
            ID = scan.nextInt();
            scan.nextLine();
            if (ID == 0) {
                System.out.println("ERROR - Book ID can not be 0. Please try again");
            }
        } while (ID == 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand your code and what you want to do you just have the line

```
System.out.println("This ID already exists. Please try again");
```

too early in your code.
You say you want to print this message after you have edited the book id, but this is not yet done anywhere in your code. (And probably you want this message to be shown, if the new id already exists before even editing the id of the book)

The last do-while loop seems to check whether the new id already exists. You can use a new boolean to check if the new target-id exists (in the same way as you check whether the first id exists) and if it does you can use the line

```
System.out.println("This ID already exists. Please try again");
```

in your code and your program should behave as you want it to.

Answer (score 0):

You assigned a value of true to the the exsistingID variable on the loop and you have this obvious code witch runs evrey time you type a valid id

```
if (exsistingID == true) {
    System.out.println("This ID already exists. Please try again");
```